# Pass data from Realm between Viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, realm

I have saved data from a form in my realm database (i.e . name, age, address, etc) and I want to pass those values to various viewcontrollers throughout my project.

In one of my viewcontrollers there is a tableview that accesses some of that data from an array and populates the cell. What I would like to do is when the user taps the cell, the data from my realm gets passed to various labels and textfields in the detail viewcontroller. I read earlier that all I need is to use prepareForSegue, but I'm not sure of the proper way to access the values so they go to the destinationviewcontroller. I will attaxh code snippits of my view controllers so you can see where I am currently.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let request = try! Realm().objects(RenterRequest.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "requestAddress")

    if segue.identifier == "HistoryData" {
        let renterMaintenanceHistory = segue.destination as? RenterMaintenanceHistory
        renterMaintenanceHistory?.renterHIstoryAddress.text = request.description
    }
}

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class RenterMaintenanceHistory: UIViewController {

    var request = RenterRequest()

    @IBOutlet weak var RenterHistoryPriority: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHistoryType: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHIstoryAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHistoryRoom: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHIstoryProblemDescription: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHistoryPreferredTimeAndDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHistoryPets: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHistoryAuthorizedEntry: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHIstoryPreferredContactNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var renterHistoryPreviouslyReported: UISwitch!

    var renterHistoryAddress: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        renterHIstoryAddress.text = renterHistoryAddress
    }
}
```

when I run the code and try to access the property I get the Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . Should I access the realm.objects function through the model to retrieve the values?

Comment: Don't include code as screenshots. Include it as text using proper code formatting.

Comment: I changed it from the photo to the proper code formatting but not all of it was formatted right. Are you able to help me with my question?